# Sturm-Liouville Problem: Possible range for the eigenvalues.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let us consider the Sturm-Liouville Problem $$y''=\lambda \cdot y$$ with $y(0)=y(\pi)=0$.

As only $\lambda \gt 0$ renders non-zero solutions, one obtains the condition $\sin(\mu \pi)=0$ for a non-trivial solution.
This is the point where i get confused, because the assignment solution concludes $\mu \in N$. What about all the the negative integers and zero? I know that in the general solution taking all the negative integers and zero into account would only modify the coefficients, but I think in general this would lead to different answers.

I would be very thankful if someone could explain me this step.

Thank you for taking your time.